# Translation (or searchable version) of *Sefer Elim* of Rabbi Joseph Solomon Delmedigo

Tags: history, hebrew, translation, ashkenazi, mathematics

Does there exist any translation of the *Sefer Elim* of Rabbi Joseph Solomon Delmedigo into a European language? If not, does there at least exist a **text-version of the original Hebrew version** (all I have is a scan of the original Hebrew, which makes it especially difficult for someoneone with rudimentary knowledge of the language).

Comment: It seems the book you are looking for is [Sefer Ilem](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/6641)? I hesitate to change the name of the book in your post because the description of the book on its cover page seems to use rhymes that end with -lim

Comment: @ba It’s ‘Elim’ like the place Num. 33:9. The book’s format follows the amount of wells and palm-trees. See Wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://hebrewbooks.org/43425
http://www.seforimonline.org/seforim-database/

Actually, acc. to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Solomon_Delmedigo) the book was heavily censored, and so it is likely that it was not translated, compared with other works of a similar nature were, because of their popularity and contribution to the respective field.  To that end there is probably no translation of it when it was published.

[That being said there was an entry at the French National Library to investigate:
On Sefer Elim](https://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb30660721j)

I don't speak French so this may be a dead end.

Comment: Thanks.The version at hebrewbooks.org makes my work significantly easier, both because of its smaller file-size and its searchability.